# 301 direct a Wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-301, http-redirect, multisite

Bear with me while I try to explain what I'm trying to do.

I have recently launched a website which replaces an existing website. They are both WordPress multisites however, the old website has lots of pages while this new website has grouped all those pages onto much fewer pages.

What I need to do is 301 redirect the old site to the new website:

```
http://website.com/name/section/info
```

now changes to:

```
http://website.com/name/section#info
```

What would I need to add to the .htaccess to achieve this?

In all honesty, I don't know where to start and I'm too afraid to try anything because I don't want to break a live website.

Comment: Maybe this: [Safe Redirect Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule as your first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/[\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /$1#$2 [L,NE,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I allow name and section to be anything? so `http://website.com/name2/section2/info2` would go to `http://website.com/name2/section2#info2` if that makes sense?